# Can you use T-SQL statements in an SSRS dataset?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a script that iterates over a CTE and executes a custom sp_executesql query for each line. I need to use the resulting table in an SSRS report, but datasets don't seem to allow for declare, cursor and exec statements.

Is there any way to make T-SQL work in SSRS ?

Comment: What error are you getting? It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I almost always use an entire script in my datasets. It is only the query designer that does not support them.

Simply write your script in SSMS or whatever then paste it into the query editor. Remember to comment out any variable declarations that will be passed in from the report as parameters.

If you double-click the dataset name and make sure the query type is Text then you can copy the script directly in.

**Notes**:

1. DO NOT DECLARE any variables that need to be passed in from your report as parameters. I generally just comment these out in the dataset query. 
   e.g. If you were passing in an Employee ID from you report parameter then your dataset would NOT need that declaring so it would look something like this

   SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE EmpID = @EmpID

Obvisouly you would need this declaring when you test the script in SSMS

2. Make sure all references to @Variables are spelled with the same case. SSRS is case sensitive when it comes to variable names.
3. Only the first result set your script outputs will be 'seen' my SSRS so make sure you only have one SELECT statement that outputs the final data.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL works fine in SSRS datasets. I regularly declare variables, use temp tables and other T-SQL statements, and have used cursor and exec statements in the past.

The problem is likely in what you are returning. The "Query" (entire SQL statement) should return only one table which should have a stable structure. Returning a row per iteration of a cursor, for example, will not work. Put them in a temp table and then return all at once after the cursor execution. You can't return different column types or names for different executions, either.

Also, don't declare the variables that you use as parameters.

Comment: My script declares a bunch of variables, creates a temporary table, iterates over a cursor, inserts for each row a query result into the temporary table, then displays the table and drops it.